# Reverse a String with Process.argv

Tags: javascript

I'm super new to Node.js and I was wondering how I can output the value of my function by typing it in Node. So if i was to write 'hello' it would return 'olleh' etc.

I have a problem understanding how to run a function in Node and how to use process.argv to do so. I know that I need to get the second value but I'm not sure how to do it if I have multiple values.

Any help will be appreciated.

```js
function reverseStr(str) {
  var newStr = '';

  for (i=str.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
 newStr+=str[i];
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(reverseStr(process.argv[2]));
```

Comment: In this case, if your script was in  a file called `test.js` you'd just run `node test.js hello` while in the same directory as your script.

Comment: Also, I hate to be the "just use a library" guy, but if this is going to get more complex and you want multiple arguments, you might consider this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/command-line-args

Comment: @ChrisRiebschlager would you be kind enough to help me solve it if I needed multiple values? Would really appreciate it mate.

Comment: You are working with array so in this case you are interested in range from index 2 to end of array. You can iterate it or selectively get index like in your snippet [This example](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_argv) is clear enough

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing is to understand what `process.argv` returns. `process.argv` returns an array in which the first two arguments are usually `node` and `your_file_name.js`, therefore to get the next argument after these two commands, you must target the third argument of the `process.argv` array, which you can easily reference through this code: `process.argv[2]`.

In your `reverseStr` function, it appears as if in your `for` loop, you assigned `i` to be a variable without using the keyword `var`. This may conflict with the proper execution of your program, so perhaps edit that to make the code itself safer.

Assuming that your `reverseStr` function is now correct, all you have to do in the command line is type `node your_file_name.js stringtoflip` and it should return `pilfotgnirts`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple values, you can either look at `process.argv` indexes greater than 2 and run your script like this:

```
node test.js a b c
```

or look only at the 2nd argument and run your script like that:

```
node test.js "a b c"
```

In any case, following code will work:

```
function reverseString (s) {
    return s
    .split("") // convert string to array
    .reverse() // reverse array
    .join("")  // finally, convert array back to string
    ;
}

console.log(
    reverseString(
    process.argv
        .slice(2)  // remove executable (nodejs) and script (test.js)
        .join(" ") // convert array of arguments to string and restore spaces between them
    )
);
```

I have separated the work because you wanted a function. However this could all be done in one line:

```
const reversed_argv = process.argv.slice(2).join(" ").split("").reverse().join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a forEach looping through the arguments passed to the script. Something like:

```
process.argv.slice(2).forEach(function(argument) {
  console.log(reverseStr(argument));
});
```